# How event loop in Nodejs exectues callback from finished asynchronous task?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, v8, event-loop, libuv

In browser JavaScript Runtime, finished asynchronous task are pushed from callback queue or job queue to callstack of v8 engine. Is it the same for Nodejs?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the text of your question means. Asynchronous operations run similarly in the browser and nodejs, though each have their own implementation of the main event loop.  There are probably over a thousand articles on the nodejs event loop you could find with a Google search and even more posts here on stackoverflow that discuss it.

Comment: I mean how is event loop executing callbacks after OS is done with async task? Does it pushes those callbacks to V8's callstack so that V8 can execute it or execution takes place in event loop ?